# How to make a read-only disk writable?

Tags: 22.10

I am using Ubuntu 22.10 as administrator.

I mounted an image file (raw, ext4) as a disk but however I had changed the "Permissions" of the disk (to "create and delete files", etc), it was read-only.

How to change it so that it can be writable?

Thanks.

Comment: need more detail.  How did you mount it?  fstab options?  Did you use chmod or chattr?

Comment: It was mountable after fsck and e2fsck. chmod did not work.

Comment: fsck calls e2fsck, it's silly to run both.  "chmod did not work" is meaningless.  Supply a real error and include it in your question.   You say you "changed permissions"  -- how did you do that?  These details need to be in your question.

Comment: Right-click on the file / disk -> Select "Properties" -> Click on "Permissions“. Thanks for being constructive. The purpose of this thread is to find the solution to solve the issue.

Comment: You should add that to your question.  Adding output form `ls -l` on the item you right clicked on might help too.  You can probably just repeat what you did and add the permission back.